# Need to generate a random integer within a specified range

Tags: c++, random, integer

I need to generate a random integer within a user-defined range. It needs to use a single variable to store the result of the function invocation, and simply update the variable with each invocation.

The function that uses the input to generate the random numbers:

```
int genRandInt (int smallnum, int bignum) {
    int randnum = smallnum + (rand() % (bignum - smallnum + 1));

    return randnum;
}
```

The main function:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int smallnum;
    int bignum;
    int z = genRandInt(smallnum, bignum);

    cout << "Enter the smallest possible number: ";
    cin >> smallnum;

    cout << "Enter the biggest possible number: ";
    cin >> bignum;

    genRandInt(smallnum, bignum);
    cout << "Random number: " << z << endl;

    genRandInt(smallnum, bignum);
    cout << "Random number: " << z << endl;

    genRandInt(smallnum, bignum);
    cout << "Random number: " << z << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program runs but it keeps returning three of the same number, none of which are in the user-defined range. For example, doing a range of 10 and 100 returns 267499385 for each function call.

Any ideas what's going wrong here? I'm very rusty.

EDIT: Replaced the initial definition of `int z = genRandInt(smallnum, bignum);` with `int z;`. Then I replaced the three function calls with `z = genRandInt(smallnum, bignum);` and it seems to be working fine now. Is that proper? Or is there a better way of doing it?

EDIT2: It appears that is a good way to do it. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it doesn't change is that you have this:

```
genRandInt(smallnum, bignum);
```

three times.  Change it to this in each case:

```
z = genRandInt(smallnum, bignum);
```

This will store the result in your variable.

The reason that your result is out of range is that neither `smallnum` nor `bignum` were defined when you called `genRandInt` the first time.  Since you assigned *that* result to `z` and never changed it, then that is your problem.

Comment: Replaced the initial definition of `int z = genRandInt(smallnum, bignum);` with `int z;`. Then I replaced the three function calls with `z = genRandInt(smallnum, bignum);` and it seems to be working fine now. Is that proper? Or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You assign a value to `z` without first initialising `smallnum` and `bignum`:

```
int smallnum;
int bignum;
int z = genRandInt(smallnum, bignum);
```

Then, your further calls to `genRandInt()` do not actually assign the result to `z`, and so your code prints the original junk value from the first call.

Comment: Replaced the initial definition of `int z = genRandInt(smallnum, bignum);` with `int z;`. Then I replaced the three function calls with `z = genRandInt(smallnum, bignum);` and it seems to be working fine now. Is that proper? Or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: @CodyHayes: Yes, that's certainly one good way to do it. For that sort of straightforward program, there really isn't much room for improvement there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't update z. It is just set once to the return value of your function.